# clickJacking prevntion method in IE8?

Tags: clickjacking

a web application which we learnt that is vulnerable for clickJacking issue. we are using IE8. upon surfing i found that we can install "No Script" but looks to be that it is more related to mozilla while we are using IE8. Even if its possible in IE8, then still is there any better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have found the answer as follows.

Open IIS, RightClick on "Websites" and select properties.
2. Select Http Headers tab.
3. Click on Add
4. Give the values as "x-frame-options" and "Deny" 
              or
4. Give the values as "x-frame-options" and "SAMEORIGIN".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The proper Clickjacking defense is a two pronged approach:

On the server, since ours is Apache Web Server, you add following line in Apache Web Server’s httpd.conf file
**X-Frame-Options: DENY**

Then using some javascript code in our jsp's:

```
<style id="antiClickjack">body{display:none !important;}</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
   if (self === top) {
       var antiClickjack = document.getElementById("antiClickjack");
       antiClickjack.parentNode.removeChild(antiClickjack);
   } else {
       top.location = self.location;
   }
</script>
```

I got the code from this link: [OWASP Clickjacking Defense Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet)

I used this for the before/after to ensure the problem was indeed fixed.
[OWASP How to test for Clickjacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Clickjacking_%28OTG-CLIENT-009%29)